# How do I delete specific start line and end line of a file in java?

Tags: java, string, file, filereader, filewriter

i'm fairly new to java. I want to delete specific lines in my text file when a user inputs the name. Here's my sample text file:

```
Name: Michael Collins
Contact: 0919023445
Date: 05/21/2042
Pax: 10
Birthdays: 10
Children: 6
Seniors: 3
Price: 8000
Discounted price: 5120

Name: Stephanie Wilkins
Contact: 09208210493
Date: 07/23/2420
Pax: 40
Birthdays: 2
Children: 3
Seniors: 4
Price: 32000
Discounted price: 30160
```

for example, the user inputted Michael Collins, then these specific lines would get deleted:

```
Name: Michael Collins
Contact: 0919023445
Date: 05/21/2042
Pax: 10
Birthdays: 10
Children: 6
Seniors: 3
Price: 8000
Discounted price: 5120
```

or at least gets moved to a temporary file and gets removed from the original file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? do you know how to read/write to files?

Comment: If you text is in a file, you might read each line, add each line to a stringbuilder but skip the lines where the name matches, then continue adding lines and write the stringbuilder content back to the file.

Comment: Could you not split by double line returns and save that as a `List<String>`. Then you have a block of info for each person and do a simple check between `Name:` and the first line return to see if the name is in that block?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is well ordered then you need to key in on where each record starts and ends.  In this case it looks like "name" and "Discounted price".   So

- read in lines and copy records to `temp` file until you see the start of record marker and the name you want.
- read lines until you see end of record marker (don't copy to temp but you may want to copy to some save file for this record).
- then read in rest of file, copying to temp. You may want to skip the next line since it is (should be) blank.
- then replace original file with temp (e.g. rename, etc)

This would be easier if your file consisted of single lines in `csv` format.  Then all you need to do is focus on the name and ignore a single line.